# Set cookie for change template with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to Set cookie and get cookie in my code ?
i want change template But with refresh, everything goes back to the default state.
Is it possible to place cookies for all changes?

**Code part 1**

```
!(function (s, a, i) {
"use strict";
var t = {
        "theme-primary": "rgba(90, 141, 238, 0.2)",
        "theme-success": "rgba(57, 218, 138, 0.2)",
        "theme-danger": "rgba(255, 91, 92, 0.2)",
        "theme-info": "rgba(0, 207, 221, 0.2)",
        "theme-warning": "rgba(253, 172, 65, 0.2)",
        "theme-dark": "rgba(57, 76, 98, 0.2)",
    },
    d = { "theme-default": "#FFFFFF", "theme-primary": "#5A8DEE", "theme-success": "#39DA8A", "theme-danger": "#FF5B5C", "theme-info": "#00CFDD", "theme-warning": "#FDAC41", "theme-dark": "#394C62" },
    l = { "theme-primary": "-65px -54px", "theme-success": "-120px -10px", "theme-danger": "-10px -10px", "theme-info": "-10px -54px", "theme-warning": "-120px -54px", "theme-dark": "-65px -10px" },
    n = i("body"),
    c = (i(".app-content"), i(".main-menu")),
    v = i(".menu-content"),
    e = i(".footer"),
    o = i(".header-navbar"),
    r = i(".main-header-navbar"),
    b = (i(".navbar-light"), i(".header-navbar-shadow")),
    m = i(".toggle-icon"),
    g = i("#collapse-sidebar-switch"),
    u = i("#icon-animation-switch"),
    C = i(".customizer"),
    h = i(".brand-logo");
if (
    (i(".customizer-toggle").on("click", function (a) {
        a.preventDefault(), i(C).toggleClass("open");
    }),
    i(".customizer-close").on("click", function () {
        i(C).removeClass("open");
    }),
    0 < i(".customizer-content").length)
)
    new PerfectScrollbar(".customizer-content", { wheelPropagation: !1 });
i(a).on("click", "#customizer-theme-colors .color-box", function () {
    var a = i(this);
    a.siblings().removeClass("selected"), a.addClass("selected");
    var e = i(this).data("color"),
        s = t[e],
        n = d[e],
        o = l[e];
    function r(a) {
        a.updateLiviconEvo({ strokeColor: n, solidColor: n, fillColor: n, strokeColorAlt: n });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code part 2**

```
        v.find("li.active").length
        ? (v.find("li.active a").css({ color: n }),
          v.find("li.active a > i").css({ color: n }),
          v.find("li.active a span.menu-item").css({ color: n }),
          v.find("li.active").css({ background: s, "border-color": n }),
          i("li.sidebar-group-active .menu-livicon").length && r(i("li.sidebar-group-active .menu-livicon")))
        : (c.find(".nav-item.active a").css({ background: s, color: n }), c.find(".nav-item.active a .menu-title").css({ color: n }), i(".nav-item.active .menu-livicon").length && r(i(".nav-item.active .menu-livicon"))),
        i(".brand-text").css("color", n),
        m.removeClass("primary").css("color", n),
        h.css("background-position", o);
}),
    i(".layout-name").on("click", function () {
        var a = i(this).data("layout");
        n.removeClass("dark-layout semi-dark-layout").addClass(a),
            "" === a && (c.removeClass("menu-dark").addClass("menu-light"), o.removeClass("navbar-dark").addClass("navbar-light"), r.css({ "background-color": "inherit" })),
            n.hasClass("dark-layout") && (c.removeClass("menu-light").addClass("menu-dark"), o.removeClass("navbar-light").addClass("navbar-dark"), r.css({ "background-color": "inherit" })),
            n.hasClass("semi-dark-layout") && (c.removeClass("menu-light").addClass("menu-dark"), o.removeClass("navbar-dark").addClass("navbar-light"), r.css({ "background-color": "inherit" }));
    });
var f = n.data("layout");
if (
    (i(".layout-name[data-layout='" + f + "']").prop("checked", !0),
    u.on("click", function () {
        i(this).is(":checked") ? i("#main-menu-navigation .menu-livicon").updateLiviconEvo({ animated: !0 }) : i("#main-menu-navigation .menu-livicon").updateLiviconEvo({ animated: !1 });
    }),
    g.on("click", function () {
        i(n).hasClass("menu-expanded")
            ? (n.removeClass("menu-expanded").addClass("menu-collapsed"),
              c.removeClass("expanded"),
              c.find(".sidebar-group-active").removeClass("open").addClass("menu-collapsed-open"),
              m.removeClass("bx bx-disc").addClass("bx bx-circle"))
            : (n.removeClass("menu-collapsed").addClass("menu-expanded"), c.find(".sidebar-group-active").addClass("open"), m.removeClass("bx bx-circle").addClass("bx bx-disc"));
    }),
    m.on("click", function () {
        g.prop("checked", !g.prop("checked"));
    }),
    n.hasClass("menu-collapsed") ? g.prop("checked", !0) : g.prop("checked", !1),
    i(n).hasClass("horizontal-layout") &&
        (i("#customizer-navbar-colors .color-box.bg-white").removeClass("selected").hide(),
        i("#customizer-navbar-colors .color-box.bg-primary").addClass("selected"),
        i("#customizer-theme-colors").hide(),
        i(".navbar-type .hidden-ele").hide()),
    i(n).hasClass("navbar-static") && i("#navbar-static").attr("checked", "true"),
    i(n).hasClass("boxicon-layout") && i("#menu-icon-animation").hide(),
    i("#customizer-navbar-colors .color-box").on("click", function () {
        var a = i(this);
        a.siblings().removeClass("selected"), a.addClass("selected");
        var e = a.data("navbar-color");
        i(n).hasClass("vertical-layout")
            ? 20 < i(s).scrollTop() &&
              (e
                  ? i(".vertical-layout")
                        .find(o)
                        .removeClass("bg-primary bg-success bg-danger bg-info bg-warning bg-dark navbar-light")
                        .addClass(e + " navbar-dark")
                  : i(".vertical-layout.navbar-sticky").find(o).addClass("navbar-light").removeClass("navbar-dark").removeClass("bg-primary bg-success bg-danger bg-info bg-warning bg-white bg-dark navbar-dark"),
              n.hasClass("dark-layout") && o.addClass("navbar-dark"))
            : e && i(".horizontal-layout").find(".navbar-with-menu").removeClass("bg-primary bg-success bg-danger bg-info bg-warning bg-dark").addClass(e);
    }),
    i(s).scroll(function () {
        var a = i("#customizer-navbar-colors .color-box.selected").data("navbar-color");
        i(this).scrollTop() < 20
            ? i(".vertical-layout.navbar-sticky").find(r).removeClass("bg-primary bg-success bg-danger bg-info bg-warning bg-white bg-dark navbar-dark")
            : a &&
              i(".vertical-layout.navbar-sticky")
                  .find(r)
                  .removeClass("bg-primary bg-success bg-danger bg-info bg-warning bg-white bg-dark navbar-dark")
                  .addClass(a + " navbar-dark");
    }),
```

})(window, document, jQuery);